# Funcion dentro de archivo externo no se ejecuta

Tags: php, javascript, html, mysql, ajax

**EDIT:** lo pongo al principio por cuestiones de respuestas.

Una actualizacion a la pregunta, ya que parece que lo que pido no se puede hacer, ¿Como puedo implementar el codigo que implemente de forma de hacer que cambie la fecha en el DOM? ¿Debo cambiar el codigo?

Cambie los codigos por los que me paso @Triby

Dejo la pregunta inicial para mantener la originalidad.

¡Hola! Antes que todo quiero pedir por favor evitar criticar mis metodos y codigos, soy nuevo y antes de aprender los metodos mas efectivos y dinamicos, prefiero comprobar que funciona lo que quiero hacer, se perfectamente que mi codigo no es el mas efectivo, ese no es mi objetivo, mi objetivo es comprender todos los metodos.

Resumi mi problema lo maximo posible, porque sino daria una cantidad exagerada de codigo.

Basicamente, tengo 2 pestañas, una con un codigo js que hace que dentro de un container (id="mensajes") muestre los archivos de otra pagina (mensaje.php), dentro de esta pagina esta todo lo necesario para mostrar un sistema de notificaciones en vivo.

El problema viene cuando intento tomar la fecha de la base de datos y convertirla en el tiempo transcurrido (Hace un minuto, una hora, tres horas, etc), hace un tiempo hice una pregunta sobre como hacer esto, tuve una buena respuesta y la implemente, el problema es que este codigo solo tomaba los archivos con la clase "fecha" que esten dentro de la pagina en la que esta el codigo (no lo que habria dentro del container, ya que esto se encuentra en otra pagina), entonces, pense, no importa, tomo el codigo y lo implemento en la otra pestaña (mensaje.php), y al hacerlo el codigo no funcionaba, como si no estuviera.

Hice una prueba para ver si funcionaba, entonces coloque el codigo dentro de la primer pestaña y abajo un div con un span con la clase fecha, este funcionaba perfectamente, me pasaba la fecha puesta en el span por "Hace 6 minutos".
Luego, tome el codigo y lo puse en la otra pestaña (mensaje.php), hice exactamente lo mismo y el codigo no se ejecutaba, mostraba "Hace: 2020-09-21 10:15:00".

Intente poniendo onloads, onclick, al activarse otra funcion, etc, pero nada funciono, no se porque razon, por lo que mi pregunta es esta:

**¿Como ejecuto una funcion dentro de la pestaña "mensaje.php"?**

O si debo hacerlo de otra manera.

Este es el codigo de la primer pestaña que tiene el contenedor y los scripts:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
          function mensajes_vivo(){
              var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
              
              req.onreadystatechange = function(){
                  if (req.readyState == 4 && req.status == 200) {
                    document.getElementById('mensajes').innerHTML = req.responseText;
                  }
              }
              req.open('GET', 'mensaje.php', true);
              req.send();
          }
          setInterval(function(){mensajes_vivo();}, 1000);
      </script>
<script type="text/javascript">
// Crear variables para comparaciones
let hora = 60 * 60;
let dia = hora * 24;
let semana = dia * 7;
let mes = Math.floor(dia * 30.42);
let anio = dia * 365;

// Ejecutar hasta que cargue el DOM
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
    let mensajes = document.querySelector('#mensajes');
    cargaFechas();
});

function cargaFechas() {
    // Recorrer todos los elementos con clase "fecha"
    document.querySelectorAll('.fecha:not([data-cargado="1"])').forEach((span, i) => {
        // Mostrar en consola para ver que no se repiten
        console.log(span);
        // Marcar como cargado para evitar usarlo otra vez
        span.dataset.cargado = 1;
        // Enviar fecha como objeto Date
        let fecha = new Date(span.innerText);
        // Remplazar inmediatamente
        datosFecha(span, fecha);
        // Crear intervalo para actualizar cada segundo
        setInterval(datosFecha, 1000, span, fecha);
    });
}

function datosFecha(span, fecha) {
    // Calcular con base en fecha y hora actual
    let hoy = new Date();
    // Obtener diferencia en segundos, por eso se divide entre 1000
    let diff = Math.floor((hoy.getTime() - fecha.getTime()) / 1000);
    // Mensaje a poner en contenedor
    let tiempo = '';
    switch (true) {
        // Si es menor a 1 minuto
        case (diff < 60):
            tiempo = 'un momento';
            break;
        // Si es menor a 1 hora
        case (diff < hora):
            tiempo = Math.floor(diff / 60) + ' minutos';
            break;
        // Si es menor a 1 día
        case (diff < dia):
            tiempo = Math.floor(diff / hora) + ' horas';
            break;
        // Si es menor a 1 semana
        case (diff < semana):
            tiempo = Math.floor(diff / dia) + ' días';
            break;
        // Si es menor a 1 mes
        case (diff < mes):
            tiempo = Math.floor(diff / semana) + ' semanas';
            break;
        // Si es menor a 1 año
        case (diff < anio):
            tiempo = Math.floor(diff / mes) + ' meses';
            break;
        // Es mayor a 1 año
        default:
            tiempo = Math.floor(diff / anio) + ' años';
            break;
    }
    // Mostrar tiempo transcurrido
    span.innerText = 'Hace ' + tiempo;
}

document.querySelector('#prueba').addEventListener('click', function() {
    let dt = new Date();

    let fecha = `${
    dt.getFullYear().toString().padStart(4, '0')}-${
    (dt.getMonth()+1).toString().padStart(2, '0')}-${
    dt.getDate().toString().padStart(2, '0')} ${
    dt.getHours().toString().padStart(2, '0')}:${
    dt.getMinutes().toString().padStart(2, '0')}`
;
    // Agregar contenido
    mensajes.innerHTML += `
        <div><span class="fecha">${fecha}</span></div>
    `;
    // El navegador podría necesitar algún tiempo para interpretar el nuevo contenido
    setTimeout(cargaFechas, 100);
});
</script>
<div id="mensajes">
    <div><span class="fecha">2020-10-05 17:55</span></div>
    <div><span class="fecha">2020-10-05 13:21</span></div>
</div>
<div>No es necesario que esté dentro de un contenedor específico: <span class="fecha">2020-10-01 06:18</span></div>
<button id="prueba">Cargar otro elemento</button>
```

Este es el script que toma los datos de la pagina "mensaje.php" y el contenedor al que lo envia.

Esta es la pestaña "mensaje.php" con el codigo que cambia la fecha dentro:

```
<?php

session_start();

include("conexion.php");

if ($_SESSION['gratuito']) {
              $usuario = $_SESSION['gratuito'];
          } else if ($_SESSION['exclusivo']) {
              $usuario = $_SESSION['exclusivo'];
          } else if ($_SESSION['admin']) {
              $usuario = $_SESSION['admin'];
          } else if ($_SESSION['creador']) {
              $usuario = $_SESSION['creador'];
          }

        $query_chat = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM chat_privado WHERE para = '$usuario' ORDER BY id DESC");

        while ($row_chat = mysqli_fetch_array($query_chat)) {
            $mensaje = $row_chat['mensaje'];
            $fecha = $row_chat['fecha'];
            $emisor = $row_chat['usuario'];
            $id = $row_chat['id'];
            $tipo = $row_chat['tipo'];
            
            if ($tipo == 0) { ?>
            <div class="box">
                <h2 class="h2-notif"><?php echo "$emisor" ?> | Hace: <span class="fecha"><?php echo "$fecha" ?></span></h2>
                <p class="p-notif"><?php echo "$mensaje" ?></p><br>
                <form action="acciones-mensajes.php?id=<?php echo "$id" ?>" method="post">
                    <div class="btn-container">
                    <input class="leido" type="submit" name="leido" value="MARCAR COMO LEIDO">
                    </div>
                    <div class="btn-container">
                    <input class="eliminar" type="submit" name="eliminar" value="ELIMINAR">
                    </div>
                    </form>
            </div>
            <?php } else if ($tipo == 1) { ?>
            <div class="box">
                <h2 class="h2-notif"><?php echo "$emisor" ?>    |   Hace: <span class="fecha"><?php echo "$fecha" ?></span></h2>
                <p class="p-notif"><?php echo "$mensaje" ?></p><br>
                <form action="acciones-mensajes.php?id=<?php echo "$id" ?>" method="post">
                    <div class="btn-container">
                    <input class="leido" type="submit" name="aceptar" value="ACEPTAR">
                    </div>
                    <div class="btn-container">
                    <input class="eliminar" type="submit" name="borrar" value="ELIMINAR">
                    </div>
                    </form>
            </div>
            <?php }
        }
            $leido = mysqli_query($conn, "UPDATE chat_privado SET leer = '1' WHERE usuario = '$usuario'");
?>
```

Btw, este codigo es copiado y pegado, ya que el mio no sabia si funcionaba por este error, asi que tome el que me dieron para comprobar que si funciona.

¡REPITO! este codigo si funciona, lo que no funciona es su ejecucion dentro de la pestaña "mensaje.php", ya que si lo hago en la pestaña contenedora no toma la fecha del div de "mensaje.php".

¡Disculpen si no se entiende algo! Avisen si falta o sobra informacion, si debo o no añadir, ¡gracias por la ayuda que puedan brindarme!

Comment: El código _javascript_ no se va a ejecutar al agregarlo por _innerHTML_ y no puedes manipular elementos que todavía no existen, en todo caso, debes [observar cambios en el DOM](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) para detectar los nuevos elementos y agregar lo que necesites.

Comment: Y no hay otra manera de cambiar la fecha que recibo de la base de datos? voy a leer lo que me diste

Comment: Por favor edita la pregunta y coloca el HTML hasta arriba, de preferencia en un fragmento de código.

Comment: Me parece que vas a sobrecargar el servidor si siempre devuelves todos los mensajes. Si los marcas como leídos al mostrarlos, entonces deberías filtrar por `leer = 0` y no solo por ID de usuario.

Comment: Oh si, hice eso, es que no pase todo el codigo porque sino seria agoviante encontrar mi problema

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hay una opción relativamente sencilla:

- Coloca el código para buscar los elementos en una función aparte
- Si lo necesitas, la puedes ejecutar al cargar el DOM
- A cada elemento encontrado, agregas un [atributo de datos](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset) para identificar los que ya se están manejando y no crear nuevos intervalos
- Cuando se ejecute la función, buscas todos los *span*, excepto los que ya están marcados: `document.querySelectorAll('.fecha:not([data-cargado="1"])')`
- Después de agregar más elementos con AJAX, el navegador necesitará cierto tiempo para interpretar el nuevo contenido, por lo que se debe ejecutar la función dentro de un *setTimeout* y deberás hacer pruebas para ver que el tiempo sea suficiente.

```html
<p>El HTML debe estar hasta arriba</p>
<div id="mensajes">
    <div><span class="fecha">2020-10-05 17:55</span></div>
    <div><span class="fecha">2020-10-05 13:21</span></div>
</div>
<div>No es necesario que esté dentro de un contenedor específico: <span class="fecha">2020-10-01 06:18</span></div>
<button id="prueba">Cargar otro elemento</button>

<p>La ejecución de javascript hasta abajo o dentro de una función que asegure que ya se caargó el DOM</p>

<script type="text/javascript">
function mensajes_vivo(){
    var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
              
    req.onreadystatechange = function(){
        if (req.readyState == 4 && req.status == 200) {
            // No remplaces el contenido, solo agrega los nuevos mensajes
            document.getElementById('mensajes').innerHTML += req.responseText;
            // Ejecuta aquí la función para activar en los nuevo mensajes
            // El navegador podría necesitar algún tiempo para interpretar el nuevo contenido
            setTimeout(cargaFechas, 100);
        }
    }
    req.open('GET', 'mensaje.php', true);
    req.send();
}
setInterval(function(){mensajes_vivo();}, 1000);

// Crear variables para comparaciones
let hora = 60 * 60;
let dia = hora * 24;
let semana = dia * 7;
let mes = Math.floor(dia * 30.42);
let anio = dia * 365;

// Ejecutar hasta que cargue el DOM
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
    let mensajes = document.querySelector('#mensajes');
    cargaFechas();
});

function cargaFechas() {
    // Recorrer todos los elementos con clase "fecha"
    document.querySelectorAll('.fecha:not([data-cargado="1"])').forEach((span, i) => {
        // Mostrar en consola para ver que no se repiten
        console.log(span);
        // Marcar como cargado para evitar usarlo otra vez
        span.dataset.cargado = 1;
        // Enviar fecha como objeto Date
        let fecha = new Date(span.innerText);
        // Remplazar inmediatamente
        datosFecha(span, fecha);
        // Crear intervalo para actualizar cada segundo
        setInterval(datosFecha, 1000, span, fecha);
    });
}

function datosFecha(span, fecha) {
    // Calcular con base en fecha y hora actual
    let hoy = new Date();
    // Obtener diferencia en segundos, por eso se divide entre 1000
    let diff = Math.floor((hoy.getTime() - fecha.getTime()) / 1000);
    // Mensaje a poner en contenedor
    let tiempo = '';
    switch (true) {
        // Si es menor a 1 minuto
        case (diff < 60):
            tiempo = 'un momento';
            break;
        // Si es menor a 1 hora
        case (diff < hora):
            tiempo = Math.floor(diff / 60) + ' minutos';
            break;
        // Si es menor a 1 día
        case (diff < dia):
            tiempo = Math.floor(diff / hora) + ' horas';
            break;
        // Si es menor a 1 semana
        case (diff < semana):
            tiempo = Math.floor(diff / dia) + ' días';
            break;
        // Si es menor a 1 mes
        case (diff < mes):
            tiempo = Math.floor(diff / semana) + ' semanas';
            break;
        // Si es menor a 1 año
        case (diff < anio):
            tiempo = Math.floor(diff / mes) + ' meses';
            break;
        // Es mayor a 1 año
        default:
            tiempo = Math.floor(diff / anio) + ' años';
            break;
    }
    // Mostrar tiempo transcurrido
    span.innerText = 'Hace ' + tiempo;
}

// ***** Esto es solo para probar aquí, puedes borrar todo el bloque ***** 
document.querySelector('#prueba').addEventListener('click', function() {
    let dt = new Date();

    let fecha = `${
    dt.getFullYear().toString().padStart(4, '0')}-${
    (dt.getMonth()+1).toString().padStart(2, '0')}-${
    dt.getDate().toString().padStart(2, '0')} ${
    dt.getHours().toString().padStart(2, '0')}:${
    dt.getMinutes().toString().padStart(2, '0')}`
;
    // Agregar contenido
    mensajes.innerHTML += `
        <div><span class="fecha">${fecha}</span></div>
    `;
    // El navegador podría necesitar algún tiempo para interpretar el nuevo contenido
    setTimeout(cargaFechas, 100);
});
// ***** Esto es solo para probar aquí, puedes borrar todo el bloque ***** 
</script>
```

En la petición AJAX a PHP carga solo los mensajes que no se han leído:

```
<?php
session_start();

include("conexion.php");

if ($_SESSION['gratuito']) {
              $usuario = $_SESSION['gratuito'];
          } else if ($_SESSION['exclusivo']) {
              $usuario = $_SESSION['exclusivo'];
          } else if ($_SESSION['admin']) {
              $usuario = $_SESSION['admin'];
          } else if ($_SESSION['creador']) {
              $usuario = $_SESSION['creador'];
          }
       // Solo los mensajes que no se han leído
        $query_chat = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM chat_privado WHERE para = '$usuario' AND leer = 0 ORDER BY id DESC");

        while ($row_chat = mysqli_fetch_array($query_chat)) {
            $mensaje = $row_chat['mensaje'];
            $fecha = $row_chat['fecha'];
            $emisor = $row_chat['usuario'];
            $id = $row_chat['id'];
            $tipo = $row_chat['tipo'];
            
            if ($tipo == 0) { ?>
            <div class="box">
                <h2 class="h2-notif"><?php echo "$emisor" ?> | Hace: <span class="fecha"><?php echo "$fecha" ?></span></h2>
                <p class="p-notif"><?php echo "$mensaje" ?></p><br>
                <form action="acciones-mensajes.php?id=<?php echo "$id" ?>" method="post">
                    <div class="btn-container">
                    <input class="leido" type="submit" name="leido" value="MARCAR COMO LEIDO">
                    </div>
                    <div class="btn-container">
                    <input class="eliminar" type="submit" name="eliminar" value="ELIMINAR">
                    </div>
                    </form>
            </div>
            <?php } else if ($tipo == 1) { ?>
            <div class="box">
                <h2 class="h2-notif"><?php echo "$emisor" ?>    |   Hace: <span class="fecha"><?php echo "$fecha" ?></span></h2>
                <p class="p-notif"><?php echo "$mensaje" ?></p><br>
                <form action="acciones-mensajes.php?id=<?php echo "$id" ?>" method="post">
                    <div class="btn-container">
                    <input class="leido" type="submit" name="aceptar" value="ACEPTAR">
                    </div>
                    <div class="btn-container">
                    <input class="eliminar" type="submit" name="borrar" value="ELIMINAR">
                    </div>
                    </form>
            </div>
            <?php }
        }
            $leido = mysqli_query($conn, "UPDATE chat_privado SET leer = '1' WHERE usuario = '$usuario'");
```

**Notas:**

- No es necesario que los *span* estén en un contenedor específico, basta con que tengan la clase *fecha*
- El código *Javascript* ya debe estar cargado en la página, no lo debes recibir por AJAX
- De la petición AJAX solo debes recibir el HTML que se va a agregar al contenedor
- El código *Javascript* de debe ejecutar hasta que se haya cargado el HTML, ya sea colocándolo dentro del evento *DOMContentLoaded* o poniéndolo hasta abajo en el documento, antes de `</body>`

Comment: Los comentarios no deben usarse para discusiones extendidas; esta conversación ha sido [trasladada a un chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/113967/discussion-on-answer-by-triby-funcion-dentro-de-archivo-externo-no-se-ejecuta).